# When to use induction in proofs involving natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, recursion

Consider the recursively defined sequence

$a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n}+\frac{A}{a_n})$ where $n \geq 0$ and $A,a_{0} > 0.$

Show that $\forall n \geq 0, a_{n+1} \geq \sqrt{A}.$

Which of the two proofs is correct?

Proof 1: Proceed by induction on $n$. Then for $n = 0$, $a_1 = \frac{1}{2}(a_{0} + \frac{A}{a_{0}}) \geq \sqrt{a_{0}(\frac{A}{a_{0}})} = \sqrt{A}$ (By AM-GM inequality). Now suppose $a_{n} \geq \sqrt{A}$. Then
$$a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n} + \frac{A}{a_{n}}) \geq \sqrt{a_{n}(\frac{A}{a_{n}})} = \sqrt{A}.$$

Proof 2: Let $n \geq 0$. Then $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n} + \frac{A}{a_{n}}) \geq \sqrt{a_{n}(\frac{A}{a_{n}})} = \sqrt{A}$ (By AM-GM inequality). Since $n$ is arbitrary, $a_{n+1} \geq \sqrt{A}$ $\forall n\geq 0$.

For the former, I did not use the induction hypothesis so I'm a bit doubtful.

Comment: I think both work just fine. If there's any advantage to the induction, it's probably that you can show that $a_n$ is never zero so $\frac{a_n}{a_n}$ is always defined and equals $1.$

Comment: Must the inductive hypothesis be used when doing induction proofs?

Comment: Technically everything implies a true statement, so if you can show $P(n+1)$ then you've shown $P(n) \to P(n+1).$ That said, in such cases the induction is just unnecessary.